# Can I assign a value to argv?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code

When I use vscode for c and c++ debugging, sometimes some command line parameters are needed(`./runFile args1 args2`). If I directly click to run, it will display `argv[2]` out of range. This is because I did not enter parameters. But if I enter the parameters through the command line, it seems that I cannot step through vscode. The method I thought of is that I use `argv[]=value` to assign the command line parameters here at the beginning of the main function. Will there be a problem with this use? And I can only `argv[0]=value` `argv[1]=value`. Is there a way to directly assign a value to argv through `argv=...`? I tried `argv[1]=value` `argv[2]=valu`e. Can operate normally. Are there any risks here? For example, how much memory is allocated for argv?

Comment: You don’t need to assign to `argv`. It sounds like you want default values for parameters when they are not supplied at the command line. to do that, check if `argc == 1` and use some hard-coded defaults. Don’t assign to `argv`.

Comment: You cannot assign `argv[1]` if there is nothing passed in. In this case there is no storage. What you can do: provide storage, i.e. allocate an array `char *argv_[] = { argv[0], "arg1", "arg2", nullptr };` and then `argc = 3; argv = argv_;`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When vscode runs your program, it uses parameters found in a file named `launch.json` to do it.

If you got to: `Run` -> `Open Configurations`, that'll open the `launch.json` for that project. By default it'll look something like this:

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "enter program name, for example ${workspaceFolder}/a.out",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

If you hover over the `args`, it'll tell  you: "Command line arguments passed to the program."

Rather than trying to modify argv after the program starts, I'd try putting the arguments you want in there, and see if it won't pass those arguments to your program like it says it will.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This method works. But I don't want to generate a .vscode in every workspace. I want to use a .vscode as the configuration for all workspaces. So is there any way I don't need to change argv frequently. For example, can the parameters be written to a file? Or enter from the console？

Comment: @cyj: [VS Code supports adding a "launch" object inside your User settings.](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_global-launch-configuration)

Answer (score 5):

> Can I assign a value to argv?

Yes.

Another matter is whether you *should*. I don't recommend it.

> For example, how much memory is allocated for argv?

There is guaranteed to be `argc + 1` number of pointers in the array pointed by `argv`. The last being a null pointer. There is no guarantee that more memory would be allocated.

---

P.S. I haven't used vscode, but I suspect that it has a way of specifying command line arguments when running a debugger inside it. Most IDE's do anyway. If not, then perhaps you can use a command line debugger.

Comment: A yepp. I forgot the final `nullptr`. :-) Please, note that the initial premise of OP is that passing command line arguments via command line is the issue. So, there is probably not enough allocation available before entering `main()`.